# ¿Cómo validar un string usando expresiones regulares y mostrar el error en javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hoy es la primera vez que toque el lenguaje de Java Script. Ya que me solicitaron esto:
Se debe crear función de JS , la
cual debe recibir un string . Este string
ingresado debe cumplir con las siguientes
condiciones:

Solo debe contener caracteres
alfanuméricos.
Debe tener una longitud mínima de 6
caracteres.
Debe comenzar por una letra
mayúscula.
Debe tener una longitud máxima de
12 caracteres.

Sin embargo al ser nuevo en este lenguaje no se si por favor me puedan aconsejar sobre el siguiente codigo ya que sient que estoy repitiendo varias cosas. (el codigo en lo que probe funciona)

````
    //let name_user = document.getElementById("campoUsuario").value;
    // se chequea el regex de que el string no tenga espacio
    var espacio = /\s/;
    //se chequea con el regex que no comience por números
    var numero_init = /^\d/ 
    //se chequea con el regex que solo tenga caracteres alfanumeros
    var char_alpha = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/
    if(!espacio.test(name_user)){ 
        if(!numero_init.test(name_user)){
            if(char_alpha.test(name_user)){
                let longitud = name_user.length;
                if (longitud >=6 && longitud <= 8){
                    let letra = name_user.charAt(0)
                    if ( letra == letra.toUpperCase()){
                        return name_user;
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("la primera letra no es mayuscula");
                        return false;
                    }    
                }
                else{
                    console.log("la longitud no cumple");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log("no puede tener caracteres espciales");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log("El usuario no puede inciar con un número"); 
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log("La contraseña no puede contener espacios en blanco"); 
        return false;
    }
}

let name_user = "San4566"
console.log(validar_usuario(name_user)); ```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes basar todo en una sola expresión regular

```js
function valida_usuario(name) {
    return /^[A-Z]\w{5,12}$/.test(name)
}
```

Donde:

- `^[A-Z]` indican que la cadena debe empezar con una mayúscula
- [`\w{5,12}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#types) consideran cadenas de longitud mínima 5 y máxima 6, pero cada una es alfanumérico
- `\w{5,12}$` debe terminar con alfanumérico

---

###### Nota

Si quieres mostrar en especifico lo que falla puedes usar un arreglo de condiciones y solo buscar si alguna condición se cumple o no.

```js
function valida_usuario(name) {
    const conditions = [
        { badPattern: /\W/, errorMessage: 'no puede tener caracteres espciales' },
        { badPattern: /\s/, errorMessage: 'La contraseña no puede contener espacios en blanco' },
        { badPattern: /^[^A-Z]/, errorMessage: 'El usuario no puede inciar con un número' },
        { badPattern: /^(\w{0,5}|\w{13,})$/, errorMessage: 'la longitud no cumple' },
    ]
    const badPattern = conditions.find(condition => condition.badPattern.test(name))

    if (badPattern) console.log(badPattern.errorMessage)

    return !badPattern
}
```

Comment: Pero como logearias por consola si no se cumplen las distintas validaciones?

Comment: Listo, la respuesta ha sido actualizada

Comment: Excelente solucion!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sin embargo hay una parte que no entiendo.
const badPattern = conditions.find(condition => condition.badPattern.test(string))

El condition del parentesis que hace ?  recibe la asignación del test ?

Comment: es una función lambda, cuando tienes un array puedes usar `arr.find(f)`, donde `f` es un predicado: recibe un elemento de `arr` y regresa un booleano. puedes conocer más [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).